# Returning error in GRAPH Api 'Invalid OAuth access token - Cannot parse access token' with valid access token

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-graph-api

Returning error in GRAPH Api 'Invalid OAuth access token - Cannot parse access token' with valid access token
[image]
My code example:

```js
let newUrl = [
    `https://graph.facebook.com/17843895178048532/recent_media?user_id=${process.env.INSTAGRAM_USER_ID}&fields=id,media_type,media_url,children&access_token=${process.env.INSTAGRAM_ACCESS_TOKEN}`,
    `https://graph.facebook.com/17844623650705330/recent_media?user_id=${process.env.INSTAGRAM_USER_ID}&fields=id,media_type,media_url,children&access_token=${process.env.INSTAGRAM_ACCESS_TOKEN}`,
    `https://graph.facebook.com/17843857450040591/recent_media?user_id=${process.env.INSTAGRAM_USER_ID}&fields=id,media_type,media_url,children&access_token=${process.env.INSTAGRAM_ACCESS_TOKEN}`,
  ];
  let tag = ['17843895178048532', '17844623650705330','17843857450040591'];

  try {
    for (let i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
      let dir = '';
      switch (i) {
        case 0:
            dir = 'nycb/';
          break;
        case 1:
          dir = 'my_nycb/';
          break;
        case 2:
          dir = 'nycb_bride/';
          break;
      }
      const getLevel = await axios.get(newUrl[i], { withCredentials: true });
 }
}catch{
............
}
```

and error:
[image]

Tried to regenerate access token - did not help
[image]

Comment: That is weird, it all looks fine to me, can't spot what should be wrong here. When you click on (or copy&paste) the URL directly from the error message and open it in your browser - same error? I am guessing the access token should not contain any characters that need URL encoding, I think they are created so that they are "safe" in that regard to begin with.

Comment: @CBroe i clicked to url,and get this error. I tried to repeat it's in Graph Explorer and get similar error.

Comment: If you run out of ideas, try again once this issue is resolved. https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/873549853878501/

Comment: According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-hashtag/recent-media#reading you need `instagram_basic` permission, but it does not loo like your token did include that? (The error message should be different though if that was it, but with Facebook, you never know.)